# Django Rest Framework: serializer.data show {} in the shell

Tags: django-rest-framework

serializer.data show **{}** in the python shell. But there are four instances with some value. And when I run django project it shows **[{}, {}, {}, {}]**. why?
I will follow [this tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and I am running my project in ubuntu 16.04

Here is my code.

tutorial/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
```

]

snippets/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())


class Snippet(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
code = models.TextField()
linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = Snippet
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    """
    Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
    instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
    instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

snippets/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail),
```

]

Comment: Can you write your code please?

Comment: I have added my code. Please check it.

Comment: Write your view class also. It is important

Comment: I think in pythod shell you call snippet-detail view and in browser you call snippet-list view. Pay attention to urlpatterns please. It has a little difference with these two url.